Employment contract doesn't include any benefits stated in the offer letter
I hope this is the correct place to ask this, I need advice regarding an employment agreement I am considering to sign or not.
I got an offer from a startup in Norway. They sent an offer letter via an HR Saas tool. In the offer letter all the benefits are written including base salary, one time signing bonus, annual performance bonus and stock options. They are also helping me relocate through a relocation agency, they are covering the costs as they told.
I accepted the offer by signing the letter online, and I got a copy of the letter. In the offer letter, there is the name of the company but no signature from company, only my signature is there.
Then recently they sent an employment contract. While I was reading the contract, I noticed it's a standard template just the names and the salary is changed with respective person. Therefore it doesn't include the benefits except the base salary. Regarding the benefits, only a statement is written telling employee can be eligible to certain annual bonus but employer can update or end the benefits if they decide.
That sounded suspicious, and I wrote an email to them telling that the contract doesn't include any benefits stated in the offer letter, and I asked them to update the contract adding the benefits as it's in the offer. They sent an answer telling that; Benefits are already written in the offer letter, it's also binding, they don't put benefits into the contract since they use a standard contract for everyone. I wasn't convinced and told them the offer letter doesn't contain any signature from them, so I don't think it's binding as a contract, and at least add an addendum or reference.
So my question;

Is it a general procedure not adding benefits into the employment contract?

Can an offer letter be binding and enforcing the company to keep the promise?

Should I insist on adding those details into the contract? Or cancel the contract if they don't do anything? I mean the interview was good, they were all open even we discussed their competition strategy and ARR verbally, but in the end they are startup and I don't know them that much.



Ask an attorney these questions.

Read the contract carefully. Does it say something like "benefits as listed in the offer letter"?

My 2c:
Whilst an Offer letter and the confirmation from the recruiter that the Offer Letter is binding would probably stand up in most employment disputes or courts.
It potentially is a hassle - and the question is, is the hassle worth it.
Whilst an Employer who operates in an old-school word is my bond and everything is done on a handshake, might take umbrage with it - articulating to them that you only feel comfortable signing a contract that lists the agreed benefits and perks.
You can suggest that they add it as a separate appendix so that the main contract is not needed to be massively changed - but yes, I would want everything discussed and agreed to be in the contract that I sign.

They will say that you already have such an "appendix" and it's called the "offer letter".


The employment contract should list what's expected of you but also what you are entitled to (salary, annual leave days, benefits including travel, health etc).

Offer letters is not binding as these can be changed. The final contract, one which is signed by both yourself and the company, is binding.

The contract, if it doesn't list the benefits, really must reference an accompanying letter or document which does list the benefits.


Considering this is a start up, they have much to learn. It's certainly risky to join but check also their period notice so that if you do decide to join and realise you no longer wish to stay, you will need to continue to work for them for x weeks.

Why is an offer letter not binding? Normal legal practice says it is just as binding as a contract. Do you have a reason to think this is different?

@DJClayworth It's only binding in the sense that you can't send one out in bad faith knowing that the offer was not genuine. It's not binding in the sense that nothing could change the agreement inbetween extending the offer and having the contract mutually signed.

I disagree. The company can of course change the offer, but they have to tell you that the offer has changed, and the employee is at liberty to decline it. But I think you will have to go to [law.se] to get a definitive answer.

I would not worry about this. In most of the places I've been employed the benefits are not listed in the contract.
There are two reasons why the benefits are not listed explicitly in the contract:

They are generally the same for all employees, and so there is no need to list them explicitly
They can change reasonably frequently, usually in small ways.

If it ever comes to court then the offer letter will be extremely good evidence that the company offered you the benefits listed in it, and therefore failing to deliver them in a substantial way would be breach of contract. Feel free to ask specific questions on our law site, or of an actual lawyer if you feel it necessary.
I'm assuming that by "benefits" you mean healthcare, vacation, pension matching etc. Compensation like company equity or options should be listed in the contract, as they can vary quite a bit from person to person.

Benefits are often company policy rather than contractual. Ask if there is a benefits manual does; there often is. But in my experience it is not always complete; for example, I only knew that my employer offered up to 2 weeks off for community service because I had a manager who was already taking advantage of that. (It was listed in the manager's manual, but that document was officially not available to us peons.)
Yes, the problem with benefits by policy is that they can change. Even when they are in the contract, the exact way in which they are delivered is often subject to change; a contract typically promises what but does not specify how.
So, yes, if in doubt it is perfectly reasonable to ask for documentation describing the benefits you consider essential. But the fact that they are all spelled out in the contract itself is fairly typical. If you have the promise in writing, you can always fall back on asking a lawyer to swat them with it, but if you really expect that to be necessary you might want to reconsider whether you trust this company enough to want to work for them in the first place.
Sorry I don't have a better answer. Sometimes you just have to decide whether you believe the job will be what they tell you it will be.

It doesn't have to be complicated, but it needs to be in writing with a signature.
Leave nothing to good intentions.
There is a lot of risk relocating for a start-up. It is worth having them fly you there for a visit. If they won't, you have your answer. IMHO.

Why the DV? Either comment or give a better answer.

Not my DV, but I think that your answer is marginal as it doesn't expressly answer the actual questions from the OP. To me it reads more as generic platitudes.

What is gained by the visit? This seems completely tangential to what the OP asked about.

@MisterMiyagi Before relocating, wouldn't you want to see the physical location and confirm everything about the company. Especially if there are questions about the job offer. It would be horrible to move and then find out it was a scam or a sham. That is why I disagree with you about it be tangential to request or even required a visit paid for by the company. It is small change.

@DogBoy37 It doesn’t fix anything about the contract, that’s what makes it tangential in my book. You can inspect the premises and ask questions all day, it doesn’t change what the contract says.

@MisterMiyagi  A real HR / company isn't going to pay for a trip without a proper offer. Doesn't the red flag of not having a clear offer yet the relocation requirement set off alarms to anyone else? In this day and age, I am more concerned than ever of possible scams. There is something magical about "Startups" to many people that seems to cause them to not be careful. Over 90% of Startups fail.

@DogBoy37 Huh? They have a proper offer. They have a proper contract. The problem is that the goodies in one aren’t mentioned in the other.

@MisterMiyagi  Let's agree to disagree. I've had friends burned over the years by very similar sounding methods. It is too easy for the company to do it right, when they don't correct a mistake quickly it is a red flag. I am just more risk adverse.
